# Django: model with multiple related fields of the same type

Tags: django, api, model

I am using Django. I have a Fixture model, which looks something like:

```
class Fixture(models.Model):
    home_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="home_fixture_set")
    home_score = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    away_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="away_fixture_set")
    away_score = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    when = models.DateTimeField()
```

I have a Team model that looks something like:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club)
```

I am able to access a list of "home" fixtures for a specific team through the home_fixture_set related_name:

```
my_team.home_fixture_set.all()
```

I can access the "away" fixtures similarly. However, I do not know how I combine the two and get the list of all fixtures this team is involved in? Eg:

```
my_team.home_and_away_fixture_set.all()
```

Note that home_and_away_fixture_set must return a queryset, so that I can filter on it:

```
my_team.home_and_away_fixture_set.filter(when__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Is it possible to do this through the model query API? If not, is it possible to accomplish this reasonably easily through a Manager.raw() query?

Thanks
Jay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Q
home_and_away_fixtures = Fixtures.objects.filter(Q(home_team=team)|Q(away_team=team))
```

or **edit**:

```
home_and_away_fixtures = my_team.home_fixture_set.all() | my_team.away_fixture_set.all()
```

<sub>thx shadfc: single query as well</sub>

Comment: Your answers both produce the same *single* query.  Don't forget that querysets are lazy so the two querysets produced in your second example are OR'd together before evaluation.

Comment: @shadfc Thanks for the catch. And looks they they produce the exact same SQL in this case.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will give the above methods a go - it certainly looks as if this will do just what I am after :)